# Calculate route's distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have to calculate a route's distance, which was drawn with the following code:

```
map.drawRoute({
            origin: [lat1, lng1],
            destination: [lat2, lng2],
            travelMode: 'driving',
            strokeColor: '#000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 3
});
```

I used the `gmaps.js` library for it.

Comment: See the [Distance Matrix part of the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix).

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is no such method in the raw Google Maps API. You are using a third-party library from **hpneo**.

Secondly, this library allows you to set a callback in the object you pass. I cannot test the lib from here. You may want to try this:

```
 map.drawRoute({
      origin: [lat1, lng2],
      destination: [lat2, lng2],
      travelMode: 'driving',
      callback: function() { console.log(arguments); }
 });
```

From there, `arguments` will contain what the callback was called with, which may or may not contain the composite distance.

Comment: got nothing from console, can I make something else?

Comment: Guys is it so difficult?? maybe some algorithm exist, help me please!

Comment: @user2440685: The information is readily available from Google Maps API itself. The problem is that your third-party library **masks** this information. You can either extend gmaps, or you can ditch it.